# JMS message format type

Tags: format, jms, message, mainframe

We are trying to use JMS to communicate with IMS region. The message reaches IMS and gets dropped since the message is not in the "required" format i.e. MQIMS.

How do we set the message sent from JMS code in MQIMS format? Is there an explicit way of setting the message format in the header? Do we need to set the LL, ZZ segments or do they get set automatically?

Answer (score 1):

There is a property on your JMS container called something like "targetServer".  Changing that to reflect MQ or MQIMS will prevent the sending of the MQRFH2 header and should fix your problem.